# How to add values from list as a row in DataFrame if values from list do not exist in DF with defined values in other columns in DF in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, list

I have Pandas DataFrame in Python like below:

**Example data:**

```
COL1  | COL2 | COL3
------|------|-------
var1  | xxx  | 20
var2  | xxx  | 10
var3  | yyy  | 10
```

And I have list like the follow: `list_1 = ["var1", "var5"]`

**Requirements:**

And I need to

1. add to "COL1" in DataFrame values from **list_1** as row only if values from `list_1` do not exist in "COL1" in DataFrame
2. In each added in "COL1" values from list I need to have values "yyy" in "COL2" and "10" in "COL3"

**Desire output:**

So, as a result I need something like below based on my example DataFrame and `list_1`:

```
COL1  | COL2 | COL3
------|------|-------
var1  | xxx  | 20
var2  | xxx  | 10
var3  | yyy  | 10
var5  | yyy  | 10
```

How can I do that in Python Pandas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use set operations combined with [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
out = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame({'COL1': list(set(list_1).difference(df['COL1']))}
                                 ).assign(COL2='yyy', COL3=10)])
```

Output:

```
   COL1 COL2  COL3
0  var1  xxx    20
1  var2  xxx    10
2  var3  yyy    10
0  var5  yyy    10
```

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to iterate through the list and call append, like:

```
for elem in list_1:
    if elem not in df["COL1"].values:
        df = df.append({"COL1": elem, "COL2": "yyy", "COL3": 10}, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: `append` is now [deprecated](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v1.4.0.html#whatsnew-140-deprecations-frame-series-append) and might be removed in the near future, you should stop using it ;)

Comment: ups - i guess I should use concat instead :)